# When using Page Factory, is it better to define similar elements in their own pages or define just once?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, page-factory

I'm trying to automate a web application and there are some similar elements in different pages.the question is:

Is it better to write Elements in their own pages or just write it for one page and use it in every other places? is there any **advantages** in any of them?

my second question is: Where is the best place to initialize Elements?

I tried to write similar Elements just in one page and use them in other places by initiating the related page but my code doesn't work correctly. so I'm now defining similar Elements in their own Pages.

Thanks for any clearance on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Each page object should contain only the elements on that page. Full stop.

If there are similar/same elements on other pages, then those pages will have the same element defined with the same locator.

Exceptions to this would be things like navigation elements that are repeated on each page, e.g. a search box at the top of the page, top or side navigation elements, user profile elements, and the like. For those, you would create a new page object with an appropriate name like header or side nav, etc. and put those elements and their locators in there.

A page object doesn't have to be a full page... it can be a partial page. The core concept is to have elements in that page or partial page defined only once and only in that one page object that represents that page/partial page.